# USB keyboard always needs to be unplugged and replugged after reboot on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: keyboard

I see posts like this

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2287740

but not sure if there is a good way to debug this. USB mouse works fine after reboot just keyboard needs to be hard reset via unplug.

Comment: In the very last post there in the linked one you provided, does your BIOS have the EHCI Handoff setting?  It appears as though someone fixed their issue by disabling that.  What type of computer do you have?